# problems with dictionary issue in python code

Tags: python, pandas

My Data Science professor posted some code that we are supposed to follow for homework. Here are part of it:

```
def create_compare_df() -> pd.DataFrame: 
 """Generate comparison dataframe for lists. 
   Returns 
 -------- 
 pd.Dataframe 
 Pandas data frame containing time metrics for selection sort algorithm  -------- 
 """ 
  
 compare: dict = { 
 "array_length" : [512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192], 
 "sorted_time": [], 
 "binarysearch_time": [], 
 "linearsearch_time": [], 
 } 
  
 for i in compare["array_length"]: 
.........
```

I do not know what is the "Compare: dict = ..." part, and wehn I tested the code, it says "compare" is not defined...

I have never seen dictionary defined as above. any idea?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: This is a type annotation used poorly. Your code should work if you remove `: dict`.

Comment: I tried that and just did a "print(compare)" and got the error saying "NameError: name 'compare' is not defined".

Comment: You must have typed something wrong. If you wrote `compare = { ... }` that should define the variable.

Comment: Is your `print(compare)` inside the function? The variable is local, so you can't print it outside the function.

Comment: Make sure you copied the indentation correctly. This is why we recommend 4 spaces of indentation, so it's easily visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare is a variable name given to it!
Your code may work if you go as follows...

```
compare = { 
    "array_length" : [512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192], 
    "sorted_time": [], 
    "binarysearch_time": [], 
    "linearsearch_time": [] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I got another problem with the code and that will be another question.

Comment: `: dict` is nothing like  type casting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the dict = {} part of the equation as it could be used for refrencing. What I would do is the following:

```
 def create_compare_df() -> pd.DataFrame: 
     """Generate comparison dataframe for lists. 
       Returns 
     -------- 
     pd.Dataframe 
     Pandas data frame containing time metrics for selection sort algorithm  -------- 
 """ 
  
     compare = { 
     "array_length" : [512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192], 
     "sorted_time": [], 
    "binarysearch_time": [], 
    "linearsearch_time": [], 
    } 
  
    print(compare)
```

Basically, you have to be careful with your indentation. So make sure there is a tab in the lines after def.

Let me know if the problem still pertains.

Comment: Thanks it works. I got another problem with the code and that will be another question.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help